# Grails, finding available views (.gsp's) at runtime

Tags: grails

Is there an easy way for a grails application to find the available list of views (*.gsp) available at runtime.

Ideally a solution will work for both application servers which unpack the WAR and those that do not unpack the WAR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's different for the dev environment and when deployed in a war:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH

def gsps = []
if (grailsApplication.isWarDeployed()) {
   findWarGsps '/WEB-INF/grails-app/views', gsps
}
else {
   findDevGsps 'grails-app/views', gsps
}

private void findDevGsps(current, gsps) {
   for (file in new File(current).listFiles()) {
      if (file.path.endsWith('.gsp')) {
         gsps << file.path - 'grails-app/views/'
      }
      else {
         findDevGsps file.path, gsps
      }
   }
}

private void findWarGsps(current, gsps) {
   def servletContext = SCH.servletContext
   for (path in servletContext.getResourcePaths(current)) {
      if (path.endsWith('.gsp')) {
         gsps << path - '/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/'
      }
      else {
         findWarGsps path, gsps
      }
   }
}
```